# postfix: how do i reject all email from certain domains

Tags: postfix

We have some domains that send commercial mailings despite us asking to be removed from their listings.

I want to configure Postfix to reject all email *from* certain email domains.

How do I configure this in postfix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions) as follows:

---

#### main.cf

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        # Reject some domains because they send annoying spam
        check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
        # Other useful things to do:
        warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender
        reject_unknown_sender_domain
        # Default PERMIT
```

---

#### /etc/postfix/sender_access

```
# annoying spammer domains
businessleadsonlinemail.com     REJECT
527media.com                    REJECT
aweberer.com                    REJECT
pathcom.com                     REJECT
```

---

Don't forget to `postmap` your new access database!